# How do i make sure that List<T>.Contains(T) works with my custom class?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I use .net 2.0 (C#)

I have a Person class, and i pupulate List< Person> p from the database.

i know for a fact that my list has duplicates, but when i try to [remove the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c/48275#48275) they don't get removed.

Does my Person class need to implement any interfaces for List< T>.Contains(T) to work properly?

Any other ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Person class should implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You should override **Equals** and **GetHashCode** method.

Comment: While this DOES work, implementing IEquatable is better because it's type safe, whereas Equals is not.

Comment: Agree. But I think you should still override your GetHashCode method. This gives you better performance.

Answer (score 1):

The example you reference is not a solution for removing dupes from a list, it is a function that takes a list and yields an iterator that will exclude duplicates.  If you need to dedupe the entire list in one go you would need to take the `IEnumerable<T>` returned from the function and pass it into a new `List<T>`.

Comment: thanx for detail, i used that code as a reference to fill a new List from the original by checking .Contains() on the new list on ever iteration

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload Object.Equals(Object obj) in your class.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) say "This method determines equality using the default equality comparer `EqualityComparer(T).Default`".

Comment: Which trys `IEquatable<T>`, then falls back on `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()`.