# How to extract duplicate value in arraylist in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a array list which have a list of a type, but all values are duplicated.

Specifically, my blog url is in my array list twice. How can I remove the duplicates?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c)

[How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Answer (score 2):

```
arraylist.distinct();
```

Make sure you have `using System.linq` at the top of your cs file.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answer is correct but just to add to it, you need to specify the type when you create the list. Arraylist does not have a distinct method by itself. Here is how you would do it,

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>();
foo.Add("sample");
foo.Add("sample");
...
IEnumerable bar = foo.Distinct();
```

Comment: Are you define it in detailed

Comment: Im sorry but I did not understand what you are trying to say. Do you want a more detailed example?