# Select an element by index from a .NET HashSet

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

At the moment I am using a custom class derived from `HashSet`.  There's a point in the code when I select items under certain condition:

```
var c = clusters.Where(x => x.Label != null && x.Label.Equals(someLabel));
```

It works fine and I get those elements. But is there a way that I could receive an index of that element within the collection to use with `ElementAt` method, instead of whole objects?

It would look more or less like this:

```
var c = select element index in collection under certain condition;
int index = c.ElementAt(0); //get first index
clusters.ElementAt(index).RunObjectMthod();
```

Is manually iterating over the whole collection a better way?  I need to add that it's in a bigger loop, so this `Where` clause is performed multiple times for different `someLabel` strings.

**Edit**

What I need this for? `clusters` is a set of clusters of some documents collection. Documents are grouped into clusters by topics similarity. So one of the last step of the algorithm is to discover label for each cluster. But algorithm is not perfect and sometimes it makes two or more clusters with the same label. What I want to do is simply merge those cluster into big one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sets don't generally *have* indexes. If position is important to you, you should be using a `List<T>` instead of (or possibly as well as) a set.

Now [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) in .NET 4 is slightly different, in that it maintains a sorted value order. However, it still doesn't implement `IList<T>`, so access by index with `ElementAt` is going to be slow.

If you could give more details about why you want this functionality, it would help. Your use case isn't really clear at the moment.

Comment: I have added more detailed description of a problem as you asked :)

Comment: @Ventus: That doesn't really explain why you need the index. If you just want to run a method for each matching item, a simple foreach loop is definitely the way forward... did you have a particular reason for wanting an index?

Comment: Obviously my language skills (I mean English) is not perfect, although I wanted to modify 2 elements in collection at the same time. Yet, your suggestion to use `List` instead of set was good idea, so problem is solved and your answer is accepted.

Comment: You say "If position is important to you, you should be using a `List<T>`" but what if I want unique entries in my collection AND order?

Comment: @whiteshooz: Then keep both a `HashSet<T>` and a `List<T>`, and keep them in sync. I don't believe there are any set implementations in the BCL which guarantee to maintain position.

Comment: In a situation where you want to index both by a numeric index and by the item itself the typical solution is to use both a Dictionary<T, int> and a List<T>, and keep them in sync.

Comment: Why? Simple - I found this on Google with same question because I want native UNIQUE entries while having indexing like a list so I don't need to if (foo.contains()) check every time. A unique-entry list.

Comment: @dylanh724: Sounds like you need your own collection which composes a list and a set then. It's easy enough to write one, but I don't believe there's anything in the framework to support it.

Comment: I came up with an elegant solution that I can post as an answer if interested (on mobile now). I made an extension method to List called AddUnique that checks if contains and returns bool.

Comment: @dylanh724: If your backing data is *just* a `List<T>`, that means you'll have linear time lookup though - one of the reasons for using a `HashSet` is normally that you want to check for element presence more efficiently than that.

Comment: @JonSkeet A practical use case could be : I'm building a mesh (3D, CG), with a lot of vertices, and I'm about to create a new triangle (triangle == 3 vertex indices), before adding the new vertices to the list I want to check if the list already contains that vertices, if so, no need for a new entry, I just want to reuse the already existing index. Linear lookup could perform poorly here. Dictionnary<Vertex, int> is surely enough good. And if, for some reason (face removing), i want to remove a vertex, I have to compute the new indices myself.

Comment: @JosephMerdrignac: Rather than adding a comment on a post that's nearly 12 years old (and which I'm definitely not going to change at this point) I would suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 10):

In the case where you hold elements in HashSet and sometimes you need to get elements by index, consider using extension method ToList() in such situations. So you use features of HashSet and then you take advantage of indexes.

```
HashSet<T> hashset = new HashSet<T>();

//the special situation where we need index way of getting elements
List<T> list = hashset.ToList();

//doing our special job, for example mapping the elements to EF entities collection (that was my case)

//we can still operate on hashset for example when we still want to keep uniqueness through the elements
```

Comment: Is that safe? I think as you add elements to the HashSet that the items may be reordered and subsequent calls to ToList() may not always yield the same order. This is just a hunch, I haven't looked at the code and MSDN didn't reveal much.

Comment: @uriDium Define "safe". The point was not that subsequent calls retained the same order, but simply to execute a function with some objects.

Comment: This works bug keep perfomance in mind while doing this. ToList() is O(N) operation.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as an index with a hash set. One of the ways that hash sets gain efficincy in some cases is by not having to maintain them.

I also don't see what the advantage is here. If you were to obtain the index, and then use it this would be less efficient than just obtaining the element (obtaining the index would be equally efficient, and then you've an extra operation).

If you want to do several operations on the same object, just hold onto that object.

If you want to do something on several objects, do so on the basis of iterating through them (normal `foreach` or doing `foreach` on the results of a `Where()` etc.). If you want to do something on several objects, and then do something else on those several same objects, and you have to do it in such batches, rather than doing all the operations in the same `foreach` then store the results of the `Where()` in a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't use a dictionary?

```
        Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dic.Add("value " + i, dic.Count + 1);
        }

        string find = "value 3";

        int position = dic[find];

        Console.WriteLine("the position of " + find + " is " + position);
```

[example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/Uf4mGw)