# Is there a Pop() equivalent in C# HashSet

Tags: c#

If I have a non-empty `HashSet<T> items`, is there any shortcut for those two lines:

```
T item = items.First(); // this can be any item, it does not have to be the first one
items.Remove(item);
```

I thought `T item = items.Pop()` would be a proper function for this, but it does not exists.

I know, it is no big deal having both lines or write an extension method, but I somehow expected a build-in `Pop()`-function, which does not rely on `First()`.

Edit:

Since there is some confusion about `First()`: I absolutely do not care about which item is popped from the `HashSet`, so `items.Last()` would be ok for me as well.

This confusion about using `First()` is the point I am struggeling with: Even I commented it, reading the code lead to the assumption, it is somehow important to use `First()` (which is not).

So to clarify it: I wonder, if there is a proper way, to take some item from a `HashSet`, have it for further usage and do not give the impression, it has to be the first or last or whatever item, but rather be clear, that any item could have been picked at this point.

Comment: Why would an unordered container have an ordered operation? It sounds like you're misusing the container if you're assuming that a certain element will be the first...

Comment: I do not care about ordering, I simply want to have an item from the set and have it removed from the set at the same time. It does not have to be the first, `First()` was just the first method, which simply gave me some item from `items`.

Comment: If you need index you don't need to use HashSet in first place.  please read jon's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3828992/713789

Comment: _"is there any shortcut for those two lines"_ - Is "no, there isn't" a useful answer for you?

Comment: Yes it is (: Is there a more appropriate way to get some item from a `HashSet` then `First()`? Because I think this caused some confusion here.

Comment: Probably some other kind of collection does fit your needs better than HashSet<T>, why do you use HashSet in the first place?

Comment: What about `items.RemoveWhere(i => /*some predicate*/)` or simply `items.Remove(items.Any())` if the item really does not matter at all

Comment: If you do not like `First()` then use `ElementAt(0)` makes same sense ..

Comment: @MaglethongSpirr `items.Any()` return a `boolean` value which cannot be passed as a parameter to `items.Remove()` since it expects a parameter of type `T`.

Comment: Well it is a special kind of tree, where each child might have multiple parents (no loops) and I want to collect all children their grandchildren from a set of parents. Anyway, I thought, having a `Pop()` method would be nice and more clear, especially since using `First()` apparently leads to some confusion.

Comment: Why downvote? This is a legit questing along the line: Draw a ball from a single urn.
Also Python has it: The pop() method removes an arbitrary element from the set and returns the element removed.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, “no, there isn’t” is the perfect (since correct) answer (:

Answer (score 6):

This is an elegant solution (i used list but you can put hashset instead of it):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> items = new List<object>();
        //code to fill the list...
        object item = items.RemoveFirst();
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static T RemoveFirst<T>(this ICollection<T> items)
    {
        T item = items.FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
        {
            items.Remove(item);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: From question: _"I know, it is no big deal having both lines **or write an extension method**"_ so, OP already considered an extension method.

Comment: I think there is difference between considering and doing, am i wrong?

Comment: An extension would only make sense if it supported `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Well, my point is rather, that using `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` leads to some assumption about the ordering (as in the discussion below the question).

Comment: Just saying. I didn't mean to say the answer is not valid. I just think it's not what the OP is actually looking for.

Comment: @SebastianWerk i think that your question isn't clear

Comment: You can make this extension method generic by declaring it as `public static T RemoveFirst<T>(this ICollection<T> items)` and referring to `T` throughout. Also, perhaps worth pointing out that there are several methods like this that were purposely left out of the core because they are trivial to write and would pollute the namespace unnecessarily.

Comment: @wardies i didn't want to make it too complicate to understand, anyway for correct purposes i edited the method to the right one ^^

Comment: What about the `System.Collections.Generic.Stack`? It has the `Pop` method.