# How to remove duplicates from a List<T>?

Tags: c#, list

I am following a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c) on stackoverflow about removing duplicates from a `List<T>` in C#.

If `<T>` is some user defined type like:

```
class Contact
{
    public string firstname;
    public string lastname;
    public string phonenum;
}
```

The suggested (HashMap) doesn't remove duplicate. I think, I have to redefine some method for comparing two  objects, isn't it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `HashSet<T>` *does* remove duplicates, because it's a set... but only when your type defines equality appropriately.

I suspect by "duplicate" you mean "an object with equal field values to another object" - you need to override `Equals`/`GetHashCode` for that to work, and/or implement [`IEquatable<Contact>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)... or you could provide an `IEqualityComparer<Contact>` to the `HashSet<T>` constructor.

Instead of using a `HashSet<T>` you *could* just call the `Distinct` LINQ extension method. For example:

```
list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

But again, you'll need to provide an appropriate definition of equality, somehow or other.

Here's a sample implementation. Note how I've made it immutable (equality is odd with mutable types, because two objects can be equal one minute and non-equal the next) and
made 
the fields private, with public properties. Finally, I've sealed the class - immutable types should generally be sealed, and it makes equality easier to talk about.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 

public sealed class Contact : IEquatable<Contact>
{
    private readonly string firstName;
    public string FirstName { get { return firstName; } }

    private readonly string lastName;
    public string LastName { get { return lastName; } }

    private readonly string phoneNumber;
    public string PhoneNumber { get { return phoneNumber; } }

    public Contact(string firstName, string lastName, string phoneNumber)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as Contact);
    }

    public bool Equals(Contact other)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, this))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return FirstName == other.FirstName &&
               LastName == other.LastName &&
               PhoneNumber == other.PhoneNumber;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Note: *not* StringComparer; EqualityComparer<T>
        // copes with null; StringComparer doesn't.
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<string>.Default;

        // Unchecked to allow overflow, which is fine
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 31 + comparer.GetHashCode(FirstName);
            hash = hash * 31 + comparer.GetHashCode(LastName);
            hash = hash * 31 + comparer.GetHashCode(PhoneNumber);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, in response to requests for an explanation of the `GetHashCode()` implementation:

- We want to combine the hash codes of the properties of this object
- We're not checking for nullity anywhere, so we should assume that some of them may be null. `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` always handles this, which is nice... so I'm using that to get a hash code of each field.
- The "add and multiply" approach to combining several hash codes into one is the standard one recommended by Josh Bloch. There are plenty of other general-purpose hashing algorithms, but this one works fine for most applications.
- I don't know whether you're compiling in a checked context by default, so I've put the computation in an unchecked context. We *really* don't care if the repeated multiply/add leads to an overflow, because we're not looking for a "magnitude" as such... just a number that we can reach repeatedly for equal objects.

Two alternative ways of handling nullity, by the way:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // Unchecked to allow overflow, which is fine
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + (FirstName ?? "").GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + (LastName ?? "").GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + (PhoneNumber ?? "").GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

or

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // Unchecked to allow overflow, which is fine
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + (FirstName == null ? 0 : FirstName.GetHashCode());
        hash = hash * 31 + (LastName == null ? 0 : LastName.GetHashCode());
        hash = hash * 31 + (PhoneNumber == null ? 0 : PhoneNumber.GetHashCode());
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I had written (if I hadn't been too late :-)

Comment: That implementation of GetHashCode() needs to come with explanatory comments. My brain doesn't operate on your level.

Comment: Can you please the GetHashCode method, i dont seem to follow that.

Comment: @Sandy, @Chris: Added an edit about the hash code at the bottom. Sorry it took so long.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Contact {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}", Id, Name);
    }

    static private IEqualityComparer<Contact> comparer;
    static public IEqualityComparer<Contact> Comparer {
        get { return comparer ?? (comparer = new EqualityComparer()); }
    }

    class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contact> {
        bool IEqualityComparer<Contact>.Equals(Contact x, Contact y)
        {
            if (x == y) 
                return true;

            if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;

            return x.Name == y.Name; // let's compare by Name
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<Contact>.GetHashCode(Contact c)
        {
            return c.Name.GetHashCode(); // let's compare by Name
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Contact> {
            new Contact { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
            new Contact { Id = 2, Name = "Sylvia" },
            new Contact { Id = 3, Name = "John" }
        };

        var distinctNames = list.Distinct(Contact.Comparer).ToList();
        foreach (var contact in distinctNames)
            Console.WriteLine(contact);
    }
}
```

gives

```
1:John
2:Sylvia
```

Answer (score 1):

For this task I don't necessarily thinks implementing IComparable is the obvious solution. You might want to sort and test for uniqueness in many different ways.

I would favor implementing a `IEqualityComparer<Contact>`:

```
sealed class ContactFirstNameLastNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contact>
{
  public bool Equals (Contact x, Contact y)
  {
     return x.firstname == y.firstname && x.lastname == y.lastname;
  }

  public int GetHashCode (Contact obj)
  {
     return obj.firstname.GetHashCode () ^ obj.lastname.GetHashCode ();
  }
}
```

And then use `System.Linq.Enumerable.Distinct` (assuming you are using at least .NET 3.5)

```
var unique = contacts.Distinct (new ContactFirstNameLastNameComparer ()).ToArray ();
```

PS. Speaking of `HashSet<>` Note that `HashSet<>` takes an `IEqualityComparer<>` as a constructor parameter.