# Maintaining a sorted list

Tags: c#

I need to store a collection of nodes:

```
class Node
{
   int Value;
   //other info
}
```

I have three requirements:

1. Need to be able to efficiently retrieve the node with the lowest Value in the collection
2. Need to be able to efficiently insert a node into the collection
3. Two nodes can have the same Value

I thought the best collection to use for this would be some sort of sorted list. That way requirement #1 is satisfied efficiently by just taking the first element from the sorted list. Requirement #2 is satisfied efficiently by inserting a new node in the right place in the list.

But the `SortedList` collection in .Net is like `SortedDictionary` and requires the key being sorted on to be unique, which violates requirement #3.

There appears to be no collection in .Net that satisfies these requirements, mainly because the self-sorting collections that do exist require keys being sorted on to be unique. What is the reason for this? I assume it cannot be an oversight. What am I not grasping here? I can find similar questions about this but they usually involve someone suggesting `SortList`, followed by realizing this doesn't work, and then the conversation fades out without a standard solution. At least if someone would say "There is no collection in C# for this task, you need to hack something together" that would be an answer.

Is it acceptable to use a regular `List<Node>` and re-sort the list whenever a new node is added? Seems like that wouldn't be as efficient as inserting the node in the right place to begin with. Perhaps that is what I should do? Manually iterate over the list until I find the place to insert a new node myself?

Comment: How many distinct values are there? how often are you inserting? how often are you reading? how often are reads going to be value based - and will that always be lowest value or will it be value x? these are some of the things i would think about to make this decision. if your not sure why not do a first pass with a normal list and use linq to select items from it?

Comment: Your solution sounds good. If there is nothing like that in .NET - coding it manually would not be a big issue. You can always have a quick look at open source projects if something like this is already availalbe somewhere. I never needed it so I don't know. And if it is not there - why not making it yourself? :) Given linq skip while functionality it should take just few lines of code

Comment: Have you look at [C5 Collections](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/)? There's probably something there.

Comment: There will be a lot of insertions and always pulling off the lowest value node. Basically I guess I want a kind of queue. Except new nodes need to be inserted into the right place in the queue according to their Value.

Comment: ***If*** you end up using a `List<Node>` that you keep sorted yourself, be sure to use the `BinarySearch` method of `List<>` to find the index where you need to insert a new item. Don't "iterate manually" if that means not using `BinarySearch`.

Comment: "Have you look at C5 Collections? There's probably something there", thanks I'll take a look

Comment: From the requirements it sounds like you need a Heap, rather than a sorted list. Adding an item to a heap is only O(log n), rather than O(n) for a sorted list or even O(n log n) for adding and then re-sorting.

Comment: @harold But if he starts with an empty `List<Node>`, and he always adds to the list through the following method: `public void Add(Node n) { var idx = innerList.BinarySearch(n); if (idx >= 0)  { innerList.Insert(idx, n); else { innerList.Insert(~idx, n); } }`, then the `List<Node>` will always be sorted automatically, and he won't ever have to call `Sort`. Of course, `Node` should be `IComparable<Node>`, or the `BinarySearch` method should be given an `IComparer<Node>` as its second argument (one can be created with `Comparer<Node>.Create` static method of .NET 4.5).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes that's not too bad and falls in the O(n) case I mentioned, because the insertion might move a lot of things. Heaps don't have that problem.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I did not know about the complement of index that BinarySearch sends when no element is found. That is a brilliant implementation in C#, I'd say! Thanks.

Comment: @Narayana Yes. Just remember that if the `List<>` is not sorted anymore (for some reason) then everything becomes corrupt. The output from `BinaraySearch` is unpredictable and meaningless in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is to efficiently insert, and quickly retrieve the item with the lowest value, then you don't need a sorted list. You need a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). Check out [A Generic Binary Heap Class](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789).

Comment: I've found that 4-ary heaps, despite a seemingly slower RemoveMin, are nevertheless faster than binary heaps in practice, even for RemoveMin. For adding items, they're significantly faster. [this is not a criticism, just something I thought you might find interesting]

Comment: @harold: Thanks for the info. I've been meaning to experiment with other heap types. I like the binary heap because it's simple to implement, and quite effective. I'll have to look into the 4-ary heap.

Answer (score 1):

Make your list_key unique by adding the object id or another unique identifier: IDs 4 and 5, both having value "1" will become "1_4" and "1_5", which can be added to the sorted List without trouble and will be sorted as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `SortedList<int, List<NodeInfo>>`, where you'll put the `Value` in the key and all the other properties in the value:

```
public class NodeList : SortedList<int, List<NodeInfo>>
{
    public void Add(int key, NodeInfo info)
    {
        if (this.Keys.Contains(key))
        {
            this[key].Add(info);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Add(key, new List<NodeInfo>() { info } );
        }
    }

    public NodeInfo FirstNode()
    {
        if (this.Count == 0)
            return null;
        return this.First().Value.First();
    }
}

public class NodeInfo
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
    // TODO: add other members
}
```

Here's some sample usage:

```
var list = new NodeList();

// adding
list.Add(3, new NodeInfo() { Info = "some info 3" });

// inserting
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    list.Add(1, new NodeInfo() { Info = "some info 1" });
    list.Add(2, new NodeInfo() { Info = "some info 2" });
    list.Add(1, new NodeInfo() { Info = "some info 1.1" });
}

// retrieving the first item
var firstNodeInfo = list.FirstNode();

// retrieving an item
var someNodeInfo = list[2].First();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is acceptable to use a normal list and re-sort it after every insert. Sorting is pretty efficient in .NET. See this thread : [String sorting performance degradation in VS2010 vs. VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156627/string-sorting-performance-degradation-in-vs2010-vs-vs2008)

Comment: Not when you have 100 million items in the list. And, yes, some people really do work with lists that large in memory.

Comment: True. If you are manipulating 100 million items and want the list to be always sorted , you will have to go for your own custom implementation of a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OrderedMultiDictionary](https://powercollections.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#71512) in [Wintellect's Power Collections for .NET](https://powercollections.codeplex.com/). That's exactly what you are looking for.