# trying to remove unique words from a string

Tags: c#

My code believe needs to remove unique instancs of the same word (Complete word).

What do I mean by complete words. Well, given the following string:

> THIIS IS IS A TEST STRRING

I need this returned:

> THIIS IS A TEST STRRING

My code returns this:

> THIS IS A TEST STRING

```
            var items = sString.Split(' ');
            var uniqueItems = new HashSet<string>(items);
            foreach (var item in uniqueItems)
            {
                strBuilder.Append(item);
                strBuilder.Append(" ");
            }

           finalString =  strBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd();
```

How can i therefore, retain an instance of a duplicate characters within a word, but remove complete duplicate words entirley?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `Split` and `Distinct`

```
var words = "THIIS IS IS A TEST STRRING".Split(' ').Distinct();

var result = string.Join(" ", words);
```

Comment: "The Distinct method returns an **unordered** sequence that contains no duplicate values" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Joe does it change the elements order ? **no.**

Comment: What i don't like in this simple and readable approach is that it removes line-breaks and tabs(due to `Split()` instead of `Split(' ')`) and that it removes multiple consecutive spaces (due to `string.Join`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter that's a good point.Thanks for suggestion.I updated my answer

Comment: @Selman22: This has another issue. Now you keep line-breaks but it won't split on a new line when there is no space between. My second point still holds true(because `Distinct` removes multiple spaces) i don't want to nitpick, +1 anyway

Comment: There's another problem if OP wants to remove only duplicate **consecutive** words like `IS IS` and not all like in this string: `THIS STRING IS IS A TEST STRING`

Comment: Gents, this is a single string, not a sentence. I loop through the spliting into new lines etc prior to removing all duplicats. So, foreach string in list etc.

Comment: @Selman22 Yes, it appears to do the right thing on your computer. I was just pointing out that it looks like the interface doesn't guarantee what the question appears to require.

Comment: @Joe: for LINQ to Objects it is guaranteed. It won't change the order. That said, MS doesn't want to give a binding guarantee. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734852/does-c-sharp-distinct-method-keep-original-ordering-of-sequence-intact

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I think it's better to have had that conversation and for you to have posted that link than not.

Answer (score 0):

bro Call this method i know its a bit complex and lengthy but you will be amazed after getting the results!

```
public string IdentifySamewords(string str)
{
   string[] subs=null;
   char[] ch=str.ToCharArray();
   int count=0;
   for(int i=0;i<ch.Length;i++)
   {
     if(ch[i]==' ')
       count++;
   }
   count++;
   subs=new string[count];
   count=0;
   for(int i=0;i<ch.Length;i++)
   {
      if(ch[i]==' ')
       count++;
      else
       subs[count]+=ch[i].ToString();
   }
   string current=null,prev=null,res=null;
   for(int i=0;i<subs.Length;i++)
   {
      current=subs[i];
      if(current!=prev)
        res+=current+" ";

      prev=current;
   }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Nope, i pass in a string that contains the word Brothers, twice and it returns the same string i input

Comment: i wonder how you are using it i passed the same input in which you are getting the same result but i am not it is returning only Brothers when i pass it two times! :O