# Most efficient way to remove duplicates from a List

Tags: c#, list, distinct

Let's say I have a List with duplicate values and I want to remove the duplicates.

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10000));

// adding a few duplicates here
myList.Add(1); 
myList.Add(2);
myList.Add(3);
```

I have found 3 approaches to solve this:

```
List<int> result1 = new HashSet<int>(myList).ToList(); //3700 ticks
List<int> result2 = myList.Distinct().ToList(); //4700 ticks
List<int> result3 = myList.GroupBy(x => x).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList(); //18800 ticks
//referring to pinturic's comment:
List<int> result4 = new SortedSet<int>(myList).ToList(); //18000 ticks
```

In most answers here on SO, the **Distinct** approach is shown as the "correct one", yet the HashSet is always faster!

My question: is there anything I have to be aware of when I use the **HashSet** approach and is there another more efficient way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a big difference between these two approaches:

```
List<int> Result1 = new HashSet<int>(myList).ToList(); //3700 ticks
List<int> Result2 = myList.Distinct().ToList(); //4700 ticks
```

The first one can (will probably) change the order of the elements of the returned `List<>`: `Result1` elements won't be in the same order of `myList`'s ones. The second maintains the original ordering.

There is probably no faster way than the first one.

There is probably no "more correct" (for a certain definition of "correct" based on ordering) than the second one.

(the third one is similar to the second one, only slower)

Just out of curiousity, the `Distinct()` is:

```
// Reference source http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,712
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return DistinctIterator<TSource>(source, null);
}

// Reference source http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,722
static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) {
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in source)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
}
```

So in the end the `Distinct()` simply uses an internal implementation of an `HashSet<>` (called `Set<>`) to check for the uniqueness of items.

For completeness sake, I'll add a link to the question [Does C# Distinct() method keep original ordering of sequence intact?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4734852/613130)

Comment: thank you for confirming my assumption. with "correct" i referred to the accepted answers.

Comment: @fubo In the end it all depends if you want to maintain ordering or not.

Comment: @fubo [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb338049.aspx) uses an `IEqualityComparer<>` , and [`HashSet<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb359100.aspx) uses the same

Comment: If you need to keep the order you can ever relay on SortedSet<> that has the same interface as HashSet

Comment: @pinturic `SortedSet` "gives" an order. 1, 2, 3... perhaps my items where 1, 3, 2 and I *like* to have them 1, 3, 2

Comment: Yes you are right so you can use OrderedDictionary<> to mimic the behaviour of a set using values equal to keys for example.

Comment: @pinturic - the SortedSet approach takes about 18000 ticks in my benchmark and is as slow as the 3rd approach

Comment: -1 `Distinct()` returns an unordered set.  The fact that the specific implementation you're looking at preserves order is coincidental - have you checked that it works the same on all the Mono/Unity/Xamarin/XBox CLRs?