# Is it effective to use HashSet to avoid duplicates?

Tags: c#

```
public IEnumerable<string> ListFoldersInternal(IEnumerable<CloudBlobDirectory> folders)
{
    return new HashSet<string>(folders.Select(x => x.Prefix));
}
```

Is it a good choice to use `HashSet` to avoid duplicates and return `IEnumerable`?

Any ideas to improve this code?

Comment: It's the most efficient way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366669/most-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list

Comment: If you call `ToArray()`, you might as well make the return type `CloudItem[]`. If the return type is `IList<CloudItem>`, just call `ToList()`

Comment: They made a method for the exact purpose of avoiding duplicates. It's called `Distinct()`.

Comment: Your ListFolders method does not make use of your ListFoldersInternal method?  if not then I'd rename them just because the implications could be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Hashset is good idea and definitely an effective way to avoid duplicates. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) says:

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.

If you want you can use LINQ as well like

```
List<T> myList = ......;
List<T> removeDuplicates = myList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

A more readable way might be to use the LINQ extension [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
return folders.Select(x => x.Prefix).Distinct();
```

It is implemented in a similar fashion (using its own cut-down hash set), although it evaluates lazily (yielding after returning each unique item).