# Checking Similar Values in a List C#

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the following code in C# which checks if items in a list are equal (a list of integers for all practical purposes):

```
intList.Distinct().Count() == 1
```

The above code works if all values in the list are equal.

However if I have a scenario where:

```
intList = {1, 1, 0}
```

then the above code fails. Can someone please suggest how I can check similar values in a list when all values in the list many not be equal.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by similar values? Do you want more than a true/false output? Do you want all pairs of identical values?

Comment: Do you want to check whether the list contains only unique values? Or what is your exact goal? Please try to be more specific and declare your expected inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
bool isDup = intList.Count == intList.Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: I think your variable should have `isNotDup` name.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (intList.Distinct().Count() != intList.Count)
{
   // the list contained at least two values that were the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq `Group()` and `Count()` the groups

```
bool allUnique = intList.GroupBy(x => x).All(x => x.Count() == 1);
```

---

by using `HashSet()`

```
bool allUnique = new HashSet<int>(intList).Count == intList.Count;
```

Comment: creating a hashset is usually a good idea, but not for just using it's count property. That's unnecessary overhead. Distinct does exactly the same technically speaking, just without creating a new object.

Comment: @Mafii `.Distinct()` doesn't but `.Distinct().Count()` materializes the IEnumberable and creates a new object - I had a simmilar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30366669/1315444) about that where you can see that `Distinct()` uses `Set<>` or `HashSet<>` internally

Comment: Oh, TIL. I'll take everything back then. Thank you!