# How to Remove same key on C# List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

e.g) I want this list [1, 2, 5, 10, 1, 2, 4] to [1, 2, 5, 10, 4]
What kind of function should I use to remove same value(key) on list?
Please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Consider using a `HashSet` instead of `List`

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order of the elements?

Comment: no just remove same keys.
someone solved this problem.
but thanks to help me 

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. It sounds like you are asking about a solution `c#` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.Distinct Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-6.0) like so:

```cs
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 10, 1, 2, 4 };
list = list.Distinct().ToList(); // 1, 2, 5, 10, 4
```

Note that the documentation does not give a guarantee that the order of the sequence is preserved. However, the Distinct method is implemented such that the order is indeed preserved, as can be seen in the [source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Distinct.cs,0ff831f61400afdf).

You may also consult this post: [Does Distinct() method keep original ordering of sequence intact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734852/does-distinct-method-keep-original-ordering-of-sequence-intact)

Comment: Oh thanks!
I don't care about values index