# List<Of T> Distinct in .NET 3.0?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, .net-3.0

NET 3.0.

Is there a `Distinct` on `List(Of T)`? 
What packages would I need to import?

If not, is there an equivalence?

Comment: Linq didn't become available until .NET 3.5.  Time to upgrade perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would have to roll your own, or change your project to .NET 3.5 or 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 3.0, one option would be to use a [**`Dictionary<,>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) with dummy values. E.g. (doesn't handle `null`s):

```
List<Foo> foos  = ...
Dictionary<Foo, bool> dict = new Dictionary<Foo, bool>();

foreach(Foo foo in foos)
   dict[foo] = true;

ICollection<Foo> distinctFoos = dict.Keys;
```

If you don't like this 'hack', you'll have to roll your own set class.

**EDIT**: Here's a version that handles `null`s in the source:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    Dictionary<T, bool> dict = new Dictionary<T, bool>();
    bool nullSeen = false;

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            if (!nullSeen)
                yield return item;

            nullSeen = true;
        }

        else if (!dict.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            dict.Add(item, true);
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle `null` instances in the `List<T>` properly.

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for your comment. Does my edit make it any better?

Comment: You have it as an ICollection. Can you maintain it as List?

Comment: @waqasahmed: No, because that type doesn't implement `IList<T>`, but you could always create a new list with those items, e.g. `new List<Foo>(distinctFoos)`

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 3 you would have to roll your own.  If you have a look at [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c), there is an implementation of Distinct for .NET 2 from Keith which uses HashSet.

This is part of the System.Core assembly, so you would need to reference that in your project, which would mean installing the .NET 3.5 framework, but as .NET 3.5 runs on the same version of the CLR, you won't get any issues doing this.  When you deploy, you'll need to ensure that either the .NET 3.5 framework is installed on the client machine, or you include System.Core.dll in your release directory.

Answer (score 0):

[LinqBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/) will allow you to target .Net 3.0 but still use Linq. That includes the [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) extension method on `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

Comment: I don't to use thirdparty stuff, and I have to include disclaimer when using the it.