# How to Quickly Remove Items From a List

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

I am looking for a way to quickly remove items from a C# `List<T>`.  The documentation states that the `List.Remove()` and `List.RemoveAt()` operations are both `O(n)`

- [List.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx)
- [List.RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

This is severely affecting my application.

I wrote a few different remove methods and tested them all on a `List<String>` with 500,000 items.  The test cases are shown below...

---

**Overview**

I wrote a method that would generate a list of strings that simply contains string representations of each number ("1", "2", "3", ...).  I then attempted to `remove` every 5th item in the list.  Here is the method used to generate the list:

```
private List<String> GetList(int size)
{
    List<String> myList = new List<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        myList.Add(i.ToString());
    return myList;
}
```

**Test 1: RemoveAt()**

Here is the test I used to test the `RemoveAt()` method.

```
private void RemoveTest1(ref List<String> list)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
         if (i % 5 == 0)
             list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

**Test 2: Remove()**

Here is the test I used to test the `Remove()` method.

```
private void RemoveTest2(ref List<String> list)
{
     List<int> itemsToRemove = new List<int>();
     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        if (i % 5 == 0)
             list.Remove(list[i]);
}
```

**Test 3: Set to null, sort, then RemoveRange**

In this test, I looped through the list one time and set the to-be-removed items to `null`.  Then, I sorted the list (so null would be at the top), and removed all the items at the top that were set to null.
NOTE: This reordered my list, so I may have to go put it back in the correct order.

```
private void RemoveTest3(ref List<String> list)
{
    int numToRemove = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            list[i] = null;
            numToRemove++;
        }
    }
    list.Sort();
    list.RemoveRange(0, numToRemove);
    // Now they're out of order...
}
```

**Test 4: Create a new list, and add all of the "good" values to the new list**

In this test, I created a new list, and added all of my keep-items to the new list. Then, I put all of these items into the original list.

```
private void RemoveTest4(ref List<String> list)
{
   List<String> newList = new List<String>();
   for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
   {
      if (i % 5 == 0)
         continue;
      else
         newList.Add(list[i]);
   }

   list.RemoveRange(0, list.Count);
   list.AddRange(newList);
}
```

**Test 5: Set to null and then FindAll()**

In this test, I set all the to-be-deleted items to `null`, then used the `FindAll()` feature to find all the items that are not `null`

```
private void RemoveTest5(ref List<String> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
       if (i % 5 == 0)
           list[i] = null;
    list = list.FindAll(x => x != null);
}
```

**Test 6: Set to null and then RemoveAll()**

In this test, I set all the to-be-deleted items to `null`, then used the `RemoveAll()` feature to remove all the items that are not `null`

```
private void RemoveTest6(ref List<String> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            list[i] = null;
    list.RemoveAll(x => x == null);
}
```

---

**Client Application and Outputs**

```
int numItems = 500000;
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

// List 1...
watch.Start();
List<String> list1 = GetList(numItems);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());

watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
RemoveTest1(ref list1);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();

// List 2...
watch.Start();
List<String> list2 = GetList(numItems);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());

watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
RemoveTest2(ref list2);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();

// List 3...
watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
List<String> list3 = GetList(numItems);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());

watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
RemoveTest3(ref list3);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();

// List 4...
watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
List<String> list4 = GetList(numItems);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());

watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
RemoveTest4(ref list4);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();

// List 5...
watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
List<String> list5 = GetList(numItems);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());

watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
RemoveTest5(ref list5);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();

// List 6...
watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
List<String> list6 = GetList(numItems);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());

watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
RemoveTest6(ref list6);
watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();
```

**Results**

```
00:00:00.1433089   // Create list
00:00:32.8031420   // RemoveAt()

00:00:32.9612512   // Forgot to reset stopwatch :(
00:04:40.3633045   // Remove()

00:00:00.2405003   // Create list
00:00:01.1054731   // Null, Sort(), RemoveRange()

00:00:00.1796988   // Create list
00:00:00.0166984   // Add good values to new list

00:00:00.2115022   // Create list
00:00:00.0194616   // FindAll()

00:00:00.3064646   // Create list
00:00:00.0167236   // RemoveAll()
```

**Notes And Comments**

- The first two tests do not actually remove every 5th item from the list, because the list is being reordered after each remove. In fact, out of 500,000 items, only 83,334 were removed (should have been 100,000).  I am okay with this - clearly the Remove()/RemoveAt() methods are not a good idea anyway.
- Although I tried to remove the 5th item from the list, in *reality* there will not be such a pattern.  Entries to be removed will be random.
- Although I used a `List<String>` in this example, that will not always be the case.  It could be a `List<Anything>`
- Not putting the items in the list to begin with is **not** an option.
- The other methods (3 - 6) all performed much better, *comparatively*, however I am a little concerned -- In 3, 5, and 6 I was forced to set a value to `null`, and then remove all the items according to this sentinel.  I don't like that approach because I can envision a scenario where one of the items in the list might be `null` and it would get removed unintentionally.

My question is: What is the best way to quickly remove many items from a `List<T>`?  Most of the approaches I've tried look really ugly, and potentially dangerous, to me.  Is a `List` the wrong data structure?

Right now, I am leaning towards creating a new list and adding the good items to the new list, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Do you have to actually use `List<T>`? Unless you need random access, `LinkedList<T>` might be a better bet.

Comment: If test 4, you can just assign your new list to the list. You don't need to faff with the removal and adding.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

List isn't an efficient data structure when it comes to removal. You would do better to use a double linked list (LinkedList) as removal simply requires reference updates in the adjacent entries.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the `LinkedList`.  What are the major cons?

Comment: A Linked List is fast to remove and fast to insert, once the desired location has been found. But in order to locate an element, it is necessary to walk the list (from either end). But since data does not have to be relocated, it is still much quicker for insertion or removal than using List. Importantly though, LinkedList, like List, does preserve order.

Comment: There's several ways that indexing can be made (more) possible with a linked list. I think it's mostly a problem that there's more hassle involved.

Comment: Another con is that LinkedLists are not friendly to modern processor caches.

Comment: Following Steve Morgan's comment, this means that LinkedList does not implement `IList`. Also, because you have to walk the collection to index, you may run into performance problems when binding to an ItemsSource.

Comment: list is more efficient when number of items is small because of high locality of reference. also its somewhat tedious to write short and readable code using linked list.

Answer (score 24):

If the order does not matter then there is a simple O(1) List.Remove method.

```
public static class ListExt
{
    // O(1) 
    public static void RemoveBySwap<T>(this List<T> list, int index)
    {
        list[index] = list[list.Count - 1];
        list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
    }

    // O(n)
    public static void RemoveBySwap<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
        int index = list.IndexOf(item);
        RemoveBySwap(list, index);
    }

    // O(n)
    public static void RemoveBySwap<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        int index = list.FindIndex(predicate);
        RemoveBySwap(list, index);
    }
}
```

This solution is friendly for memory traversal, so even if you need to find the index first it will be very fast.

Notes:

- Finding the index of an item must be O(n) since the list must be unsorted.
- Linked lists are slow on traversal, especially for large collections with long life spans.

Comment: In my tests, your method was 10% faster than plain list.remove

Comment: If you're using (say) 100 entries, using OP's requirement of removing every 5th entry, you'd be wanting to remove 20 entries, but the 85th, 90th, 95th and 100th would be moved to earlier in the list before they could be removed and so would be skipped.
That could be why it's faster?

Comment: Zac, this method I mentioned is applicable only when order does not matter and you just want a bag of stuff. If you want to specifically remove elements according to their position, you shouldn't use this method.

Answer (score 20):

If you're happy creating a new list, you don't have to go through setting items to null. For example:

```
// This overload of Where provides the index as well as the value. Unless
// you need the index, use the simpler overload which just provides the value.
List<string> newList = oldList.Where((value, index) => index % 5 != 0)
                              .ToList();
```

However, you might want to look at alternative data structures, such as `LinkedList<T>` or `HashSet<T>`. It really depends on what features you need from your data structure.

Answer (score 14):

I feel a `HashSet`, `LinkedList` or `Dictionary` will do you much better.

Answer (score 4):

You could always remove the items from the end of the list. List removal is O(1) when performed on the last element since all it does is decrement count. There is no shifting of next elements involved. (which is the reason why list removal is O(n) generally)

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
  list.RemoveAt(i);
```

Comment: This would require a pre-sort to put items to be removed at end of list. `List.Sort` uses `Array.Sort` which is `O(nlogn)` at best and `O(n^2)` at worst.

Answer (score 4):

Or you could do this:

```
List<int> listA;
List<int> listB;
```

...

```
List<int> resultingList = listA.Except(listB);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok try RemoveAll used like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    List<Int32> test = GetList(500000);
    watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
    watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
    test.RemoveAll( t=> t % 5 == 0);
    List<String> test2 = test.ConvertAll(delegate(int i) { return i.ToString(); });
    watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine((500000 - test.Count).ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

}

static private List<Int32> GetList(int size)
{
    List<Int32> test = new List<Int32>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        test.Add(i);
    return test;
}
```

this only loops twice and removes eactly 100,000 items

My output for this code:

```
00:00:00.0099495 
00:00:00.1945987 
1000000
```

Updated to try a HashSet

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        do
        {
            // Test with list
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            List<Int32> test = GetList(500000);
            watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            List<String> myList = RemoveTest(test);
            watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine((500000 - test.Count).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Test with HashSet
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            HashSet<String> test2 = GetStringList(500000);
            watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            HashSet<String> myList2 = RemoveTest(test2);
            watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine((500000 - test.Count).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

    }

    static private List<Int32> GetList(int size)
    {
        List<Int32> test = new List<Int32>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
            test.Add(i);
        return test;
    }

    static private HashSet<String> GetStringList(int size)
    {
        HashSet<String> test = new HashSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
            test.Add(i.ToString());
        return test;
    }

    static private List<String> RemoveTest(List<Int32> list)
    {
        list.RemoveAll(t => t % 5 == 0);
        return list.ConvertAll(delegate(int i) { return i.ToString(); });
    }

    static private HashSet<String> RemoveTest(HashSet<String> list)
    {
        list.RemoveWhere(t => Convert.ToInt32(t) % 5 == 0);
        return list;
    }
```

This gives me:

```
00:00:00.0131586
00:00:00.1454723
100000

00:00:00.3459420
00:00:00.2122574
100000
```

Comment: This is a good approach. Unlike other answers, it does not create a new list in memory. And it's a lot faster than removing items one by one.

Answer (score 3):

I've found when dealing with large lists, this is often faster.  The speed of the Remove and finding the right item in the dictionary to remove, more than makes up for creating the dictionary.  A couple things though, the original list has to have unique values, and I don't think the order is guaranteed once you are done.

```
List<long> hundredThousandItemsInOrignalList;
List<long> fiftyThousandItemsToRemove;

// populate lists...

Dictionary<long, long> originalItems = hundredThousandItemsInOrignalList.ToDictionary(i => i);

foreach (long i in fiftyThousandItemsToRemove)
{
    originalItems.Remove(i);
}

List<long> newList = originalItems.Select(i => i.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: You could make the 50k list the dictionary, then iterate once over the 100k and check in the 50k. That'd save you 50k dictionarifications. This is still a spectacularly ugly solution.

Comment: in support of NeilPearson. We had code that used two list and the RemoveAll. By only changing the main list to use .ToDictionary(x=>x) and chaginge the removeall to use the dictionary contains we went from a couple of minutes to under a second.

Comment: .... and this could be a HashSet instead of a dictionary since we are really just concerned with the key

Comment: "I don't think the order is guaranteed once you are done." Order is never guaranteed in a Dictionary. But there's OrderedDictionary if you need that.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are faster than LinkedLists until n gets realy big. The reason for this is because so called cache misses occur quite more frequently using LinkedLists than Lists. Memory look ups are quite expensive. As a list is implemented as an array the CPU can load a bunch of data at once because it knows the required data is stored next to each other. However a linked list does not give the CPU any hint which data is required next which forces the CPU to do quite more memory look ups. By the way. With term memory I mean RAM.

For further details take a look at: https://jackmott.github.io/programming/2016/08/20/when-bigo-foolsya.html

Answer (score 1):

The other answers (and the question itself) offer various ways of dealing with this "slug" (slowness bug) using the built-in .NET Framework classes.

But if you're willing to switch to a third-party library, you can get better performance simply by changing the data structure, and leaving your code unchanged except for the list type.

The Loyc Core libraries include two types that work the same way as `List<T>` but can remove items faster:

- [`DList<T>`](http://core.loyc.net/collections/dlist.html) is a simple data structure that gives you a 2x speedup over `List<T>` when removing items from random locations
- [`AList<T>`](http://core.loyc.net/collections/alists-part1.html) is a sophisticated data structure that gives you a large speedup over `List<T>` when your lists are very long (but may be slower when the list is short).

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use a List as an underlying structure, you can use the following extension method, which does the heavy lifting for you.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Library.Extensions
{
    public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveRange<T>(this List<T> list, IEnumerable<T> range)
        {
            var removed = list.Intersect(range).ToArray();
            if (!removed.Any())
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
            }

            var remaining = list.Except(removed).ToArray();
            list.Clear();
            list.AddRange(remaining);

            return removed;
        }
    }
}
```

A simple stopwatch test gives results in about 200ms for removal. Keep in mind this is not a real benchmark usage.

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = Enumerable
                .Range(0, 500_000)
                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                .ToList();

            var allFifthItems = list.Where((_, index) => index % 5 == 0).ToArray();

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            list.RemoveRange(allFifthItems);
            sw.Stop();

            var message = $"{allFifthItems.Length} elements removed in {sw.Elapsed}";
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

Output:

> 100000 elements removed in 00:00:00.2291337