# Excluding items using linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have two lists being returned via LINQ. My goal is to return all the items from the 'defaults' list minus what is in the 'notDefaults' list.

I'm currently doing this via two nested for loops and using 'RemoveAt'. Could this be done with only one LINQ statement? Basically, I need everything in the 'defaults' list unless the item exists in the table 'AssetPayrollMarkupOverrides'.

I'm apprehensive about using 'RemoveAt' since [it appears to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926554/how-to-quickly-remove-items-from-a-list).

```
var defaults = (from a in dbcontext.Assets
    join b in dbcontext.AssetAddresses on a.AssetID equals b.AssetID
    join c in dbcontext.Addresses on b.AddressID equals c.AddressID
    join d in dbcontext.StateLookups on c.StateID equals d.StateID
    where d.ShortName == state
    select new AssetMarkup()
    {
        AssetId = a.AssetID,
        AssetName = a.AssetName,
        Seg1_Code = a.Seg1_Code,
    }).ToList();


var notDefaults = (from a in dbcontext.Assets
    join b in dbcontext.AssetAddresses on a.AssetID equals b.AssetID
    join c in dbcontext.Addresses on b.AddressID equals c.AddressID
    join d in dbcontext.StateLookups on c.StateID equals d.StateID
    join e in dbcontext.AssetPayrollMarkupOverrides on a.AssetID equals e.AssetID
    where d.ShortName == state
    select new AssetMarkup()
    {
        AssetId = a.AssetID,
        AssetName = a.AssetName,
        Seg1_Code = a.Seg1_Code,
        ShortName = d.ShortName,
        OfficePercentage = e.OfficePercentage,
        MaintenancePercentage = e.MaintenancePercentage,
        Note = e.Note
    }).ToList();
```

I originally had it this way to make sure the two lists matched:

```
var defaults = (from a in dbcontext.Assets
    join b in dbcontext.AssetAddresses on a.AssetID equals b.AssetID
    join c in dbcontext.Addresses on b.AddressID equals c.AddressID
    join d in dbcontext.StateLookups on c.StateID equals d.StateID
    where d.ShortName == state
    select new AssetMarkup()
    {
        AssetId = a.AssetID,
        AssetName = a.AssetName,
        Seg1_Code = a.Seg1_Code,
        ShortName = d.ShortName,
        OfficePercentage = dbcontext.PayrollMarkups.Where(x => x.StateID == c.StateID).Select(x => x.OfficePercentage).FirstOrDefault(),
        MaintenancePercentage = dbcontext.PayrollMarkups.Where(x => x.StateID == c.StateID).Select(x => x.MaintenancePercentage).FirstOrDefault(),
        Note = dbcontext.AssetPayrollMarkupOverrides.Where(x => x.AssetID == a.AssetID).Select(x => x.Note).FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();

var notDefaults = (from a in dbcontext.Assets
   join b in dbcontext.AssetAddresses on a.AssetID equals b.AssetID
   join c in dbcontext.Addresses on b.AddressID equals c.AddressID
   join d in dbcontext.StateLookups on c.StateID equals d.StateID
   join e in dbcontext.AssetPayrollMarkupOverrides on a.AssetID equals e.AssetID
   where d.ShortName == state
   select new AssetMarkup()
   {
       AssetId = a.AssetID,
       AssetName = a.AssetName,
       Seg1_Code = a.Seg1_Code,
       ShortName = d.ShortName,
       OfficePercentage = dbcontext.PayrollMarkups.Where(x => x.StateID == c.StateID).Select(x => x.OfficePercentage).FirstOrDefault(),
       MaintenancePercentage = dbcontext.PayrollMarkups.Where(x => x.StateID == c.StateID).Select(x => x.MaintenancePercentage).FirstOrDefault(),
       Note = dbcontext.AssetPayrollMarkupOverrides.Where(x => x.AssetID == a.AssetID).Select(x => x.Note).FirstOrDefault()
   }).ToList();

return Json(defaults.Except(notDefaults).OrderBy(x => x.AssetName).ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var notDefaultIds = notDefaults.Select(nd => nd.AssetID);
var result = defaults.Where(def => !notDefaultIds.Any(id => id == def.AssetID);
```

If you want to reduce db roundtrips, move `ToList()` from `notDefaults`, `defaults` to `result`;

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Except`

```
var remaining = defaults.Except(notDefaults);
```

You may need to ensure your equality comparer on `AssetMarkup` is set to compare the objects in a non reference-based way.

See here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I apologize for not stating this in my original post but I did attempt to use 'Except' but it appeared to not be working. I also added the same OfficePercentage, MaintenancePercentage and Notes into each linq statement to make sure they matched exactly and 'Except' still appeared to not be working.

return Json(defaults.Except(notDefaults).OrderBy(x => x.AssetName).ToDataSourceResult(request));

Comment: You man need to ensure you have Equals overloaded in a way that compares AssetMarkup objects properly.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29) of the two sets. The Linq [Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) method is designed to do this (you could use the overload that takes an IEqualityComparer):

```
public class AssetMarkupComparer : IEqualityComparer<AssetMarkup>
{
    public bool Equals(AssetMarkup am1, AssetMarkup am2)
    {
        return am1.AssetId == am2.AssetId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(AssetMarkup obj)
    {
        return obj.AssetId.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var complement = defaults.Except(notDefaults, new AssetMarkupComparer());
```

You'd need to account for nulls in the comparer methods but this is just a skeleton example.