# List<> Iteration performance

Tags: c#, list, iteration

Hi I have a question with regards to the efficiency of iterating through a list of values.

I am wondering say you have to look through a list of values pulling out those values that match your current search criteria, does it make sense to remove the match you have found once you have found it, resulting in a smaller list of values to search through on the next iteration. Or does this make little difference. Here is my code.

```
foreach (Project prj in projectList)
        {
            string prjCode = prj.Code;

            var match = usersProjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == prjCode);
            if (match != null)
            {
                usersProjects.Remove(match);
                //More logic here
            }
        }
```

Basically I am searching for a project code that corresponds to a user from a list of all projects. 
Say there are 50 projects, and the user has access to 20 of them. Does removing the found project every loop reducing the overall project count make the iteration more efficient? Thanks.

Comment: why not time it to find out?

Comment: No it doesn't. This results in unncessary adjustment of data in the list. Which is more inefficient than just looping through the list and getting the list of projects that satisfy the condition.

Comment: By the way If I were you I would turn usersProjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == prjCode) to a dictionary usersProjects.ToDictionary(x => x.Code, y =>y). So you can do a try get value vs iterating through the list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926554/how-to-quickly-remove-items-from-a-list

Comment: Thanks @Jagannath I did think that altering the list would be more 'costly' than leaving the list as it was. Also TYY I will look at trying that. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend changing the list - that, itself, is slow, order O(n).

Use a prepared lookup to do what you want instead of `FirstOrDefault()`

```
var projectLookup = usersProjects.ToLookup((x) => x.Code);

foreach (Project prj in projectList)
    {
        string prjCode = prj.Code;

        var match = projectLookup[prjCode].FirstOrDefault()

        if (match != null)
        {
            //More logic here
        }
    }
```

Note that `ToLookup()` is expensive so you want to retain the lookup if possible - consider recreating it only when `userProjects` changes. After that, actually using the lookup to retrieve a match requires only constant time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a group join for this:

```
var matches =
    from prj in projectList
    join x in usersProjects on prj.Code equals x.Code into xs
    where xs.Any()
    select xs.First();
```

Actually, a slightly better query would be:

```
var matches =
    from prj in projectList
    join x in usersProjects on prj.Code equals x.Code into xs
    from x1 in xs.Take(1)
    select x1;
```

If you then need to remove them from the `usersProjects` list you would need to do this:

```
foreach (var match in matches)
{   
    usersProjects.Remove(match);
}
```

But, if you just want to know what's left in the `usersProjects` **if** you removed the matches you could then just do this:

```
var remainingUsersProjects = usersProjects.Except(matches);
```

At the end of all of this the only thing you need to do is **time** all of the options to see what is faster.

But I would think that it really won't matter unless your lists are huge. Otherwise I'd go with the simplest to understand code so that you can maintain your project in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loop and multiple `FirstOrDefault()` calls, you  can use simple `Where()` method to get all user projects:

```
userProjects = userProjects.Where(up => projectList.All(p => up.Code != p.Code))
```