# What is the fastest way to remove a single item from List<T> with no duplicates where order matters?

Tags: c#, list, indexof

I have a list of items with no duplicates where order matters.

Periodically I need to remove an item from this list.

A practical example is list bound UI control such as a `DataGridView` that allows delete.

The user expects to view the items in a certain order and so post delete the remaining items should retain their ordering.

Here is some sample code that seems to indicate list item removal is `O(n)` because

(1) the list must be iterated to find the item to delete by matching criteria

(2) the `List.RemoveAt` method must shuffle down the remaining items

```
public class Item
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
}

public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

public void AddItem(string name, string description)
{
  Items.Add(new Item {Name=name, Description=description});
}

public void RemoveItem(string name)
{
  for (int i=0; i<Items.Count; i++)
  {
    if (Items[i].Name == name)
    {
      Items.RemoveAt(i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Could there be a faster way ?

`LinkedList<T>` won't work because it can't be indexed for scrolling and pagination.  Also for high item count `LinkedList<T>` item removal is actually slower due to cache misses.

Comment: You cannot remove items from a collection you are iterating on and you will get an exception

Comment: Do you need to be able to use `Items[someNumber]` to access the list? If so switching to a [`LinkedList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8) would give you better performance in removing arbitrary items in the list.

Comment: Your remove implies search and remove. Search complexity for arrays (which the List is sort of) is O(n). If you require lesser complexity you need another data structure (for example dictionary which would keep item names to quickly access the items).

Comment: I need to retain the original order items were added to list. I suppose I could use `SortedDictionary<int,Item>` but it seems overkill and would add overhead.

Comment: Why would `LinkedList<T>` improve performance ? Seems you'd still need to a linear scan so it's `O(n)`.

Comment: If you used a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`, you wouldn't have to make the extra call to `IndexOf° to get the index.

Comment: A linked list would be faster when the search result is near the start, since the remove operation doesn't require an iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Quickly Remove Items From a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926554/how-to-quickly-remove-items-from-a-list)

Answer (score 4):

`RemoveAt` takes O(n) time. Because it has to shift items to left, starting from index `i` to `n` (`Items.Count`). Similar for `IndexOf`.

Here is asymptotic estimation of your code:

```
public void RemoveItem(string name)
{
  foreach (var item in Items) //n times
  {
    if (item.Name == name)
    {
      Items.RemoveAt(Items.IndexOf(position)); // O(n) + O(n) => O(n)
    }
  }

  // => O(n * n)
}
```

it runs in O(n ^ 2) time.

How about this code?

```
for (int i = Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) // n times
{
    if (Items[i].Name == name)
    {
        Items.RemoveAt(i); //O(n)
    }
}
```

So this also runs in O(n ^ 2)

but this code:

```
Items.RemoveAll(i => item.Name == name);
```

runs in O(n) time. You should see the implementation of this method for proof.
`RemoveAll` iterates ONCE through the items of the list, and if the criteria is met, it will start also shifting while iterating. This shifting in each step is a single assignment, i.e. O(1). Therefore the whole method runs in O(n) time, which is by far faster than your implementation.

**UPDATE**:
The question now contains a `break;` after the remove line.

In that code finding items will stop after found and removing would start which will cost O(n) + O(n) => O(n).

So there won't be any asymptotic difference between the code in question and `RemoveAll`.

So it is not any faster and CANNOT BE, but still `RemoveAll` is a cleaner code IMHO.

Comment: O(n) + O(n) which is search and remove isn't O(n*n). It's still O(n).

Comment: Yes. n * O(n) is O(n ^ 2). n is for loop, O(n) is for that line :)

Comment: Once element is found it's removed only once. Thers is no **n** remove procedures. That's why you are doing search once which is O(n) and you are doing remove once which is again O(n), in total you have O(n) + O(n).

Comment: Your confusion is can be based on the fact that you missed break operator from the original question.

Comment: Ok the `break;` after remove was only added 2 minutes!. I had copied and pasted the original question :)

Comment: Well it was actually added 20 min ago but anyway I think you need to adjust your answer.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - in the original question I forgot to mention no duplicate items and the `break;` - but I don't think that justifies downvoting my question

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop nor a custom method. Try this:

```
Items.RemoveAll(i => item.Name == name);
```

**Edit**
As @Gian Paolo commented, for `List` data structure, in the best case it has a complexity of O(n). If you want a better performance, you can consider checking other data structures including `LinkedList`, `Dictionary`, or `HashSet`.

Comment: Yes, it is, because this is working and your solution does not work. ;o)

Comment: And even if your solution was working it would still be faster because the extra `IndexOf`call you do takes up a lot of time.

Comment: @BaltoStar This is a very clean way to remove items matching the condition. Possibly you can implement something faster, but if you really require some noticeable difference, it means you should look for a different data structure. A List will always require to scan every element within it. No alghoritm can be much faster than that, you will always have a O(n) complexity.
So, if you decide to use a List, go for the cleanest code

Comment: agreed cleaner ( and I knew about the remove extension methods that take a predicate ) but the spirit of my question is performance

Comment: @BaltoStar, `RemoveAll` is actually a method of `List<T>`, and I assume is quite optimized. you can check the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,82567b42bbfc416e)

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a traditional loop over your items and remove if name match like,

```
for (int i = Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (Items[i].Name == name)
    {
        Items.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose the direction of iteration doesn't matter ?  It's random the index at which the matching item is found so the avg shifts in the underlying array should be same for starting at 0 or count-1

Comment: @BaltoStar, Yes, `count-1` only for iteration purpose. not sure but your list will preserve order i think :)