# How figure out where this closure object is being created?

Tags: c#, cil

While trying to track down a memory leak, I'm having my application do this:

```
using DataTarget dataTarget = DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach(Environment.ProcessId);
ClrRuntime clr = dataTarget.ClrVersions.First().CreateRuntime();
```

I'm then looking through clr.Heap for clues.

What I'm seeing, is that there is a closure object being created and not released, the ClrObject.Type is set to
`Stuff<OtherStuff>+<>c__DisplayClass7_0`

The problem is, Stuff<OtherStuff> (not its real name) is used in a very few places, and none of them look like they would be creating a lambda in need of a closure.

Is the closure suffix "c__DisplayClass7_0" assigned at compile time, such that I should be able to find it by inspecting the generated CIL?  I tried to a simple "find all" and nothing showed up.

EDIT

I installed ILSpy, that's a really cool tool!  Using the instructions from JL0PD, I was able to find the function that was creating the closure object.

My generic class has a data member `readonly List<WeakReference<T>> References` and a member function for clearing out the objects that have been released.  The guts of it originally looked like this:

```
lock (ThreadLock)
{
   for (int i = References.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      if (!References[i].TryGetTarget(out T? t) || (t is null))
      {
         References.RemoveAt(i);
      }
   }
}
```

But there were times when a large data analysis completed, and a bunch of objects were freed, and the function was calling RemoveAt() hundreds of thousands of times, and it was REALLY slow.

So I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926554/how-to-quickly-remove-items-from-a-list/6926598), and changed the function to look like this:

```
lock (ThreadLock)
{
   WeakReference<T>? remove = null;
   for (int i = References.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      if (!References[i].TryGetTarget(out T? t) || (t is null))
      {
         if (remove is null)
            remove = References[i];
         else
            References[i] = remove;
      }
   }
   if (remove is not null)
      References.RemoveAll(x => x == remove);
}
```

The closure object is created right at the top of the function, and from the IL I can see that the only thing it contains is 'remove'.  I tried changing the line to say `References.RemoveAll(static x => x == remove)` but of course that didn't compile.

Comment: I don't suppose you use Resharper do you?  If you do, there's a great plugin you can get named "Heap Allocations Viewer" for it that literally underlines in code whenever a closure is being created.

Comment: *"Is the closure suffix "c__DisplayClass7_0" assigned at compile time, such that I should be able to find it by inspecting the generated CIL?*" In principle, yes, but decompilation tools might "helpfully" hide those generated classes and re-construct the original lambda expression instead. Check if your decompiler has such an option and disable it.

Comment: In ILSpy you can find it by following steps: 1. Find enclosing class (in this case it's `Stuff<T>`); 2. Find nested class called `<>c__DisplayClass7_0`; 3. Find a field; 4. Click with RMB -> *analyze*; 5. Expand `Read by` section in *analyze* window; 6. Look through method and find guilty

Comment: If you are one of these complete a**hats who downvote a question without giving any reason why, please at least have the basic level of common human courtesy to give some hint.  The arrow clearly states it's for "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and none of those apply to this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You will notice that JL0PD was able to find the question clear enough that they were able to provide a useful answer!  Please learn from them what StackOverflow is all about.