# how to remove the duplicate values from string list in c#

Tags: c#

i used this code:

```
List<string> lists=new List<string>("apple","orange","banana","apple","mang0","orange");
string names;
names=lists.Distinct()
```

is that correct?

Comment: I have corrected your question.

Comment: i want remove duplicate values from string list. using Distinct  its possible?

Comment: [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the variable `names` has to be a collection. The `Distinct` method returns an enumerator, so you probably want to enumerate the result and realise it as a list:

```
List<string> names = lists.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list, then check two and two:

```
list.Sort();
Int32 index = 0;
while (index < list.Count - 1)
{
  if (list[index] == list[index + 1])
    list.RemoveAt(index);
else
    index++;
}
```