# How to remove duplicate value from ARRAYLIST

Tags: c#

I have one arraylist which contains values from a different database, but it stores some duplicate values so, I want to remove duplicate values and store only unique value in Array List.

How can this be done?

Comment: How are you adding values in ArrayList?

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @AVD this would have be confirmed duplicate once the OP answers my question about the version of the framework. If he is using .NET 1.1 the dupe answer won't be of much help to him.

Comment: i am adding the value for dataset of query. so remove duplicate value.

Comment: OK, thanks @MiteshMachhi. Now go and read the dupe.

Comment: why you giving my question as downvote ?

Answer (score 12):

Let's try another method. Instead removing duplicates, avoid adding any duplicates. This might be more efficient in your environment.
Here's a sample code:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<string>();
foreach (string aString in myList)
{
    if (!myList.Contains( aString ))
    {
        myList.Add(aString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can replace your ArrayList with a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.90).aspx).  From the documentation:

```
The HashSet<T> class provides high performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.
```

If it's absolutely necessary to use an ArrayList, you could use some Linq to remove duplicates with the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) command.

```
var distinctItems = arrayList.Distinct()
```

Answer (score 3):

you can using This code when work with an ArrayList

```
ArrayList arrayList;
//Add some Members :)
arrayList.Add("ali");
arrayList.Add("hadi");
arrayList.Add("ali");

//Remove duplicates from array
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.Count; i++)
    {
       for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayList.Count ; j++)
           if (arrayList[i].ToString() == arrayList[j].ToString())
                 arrayList.Remove(arrayList[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very elegant. I have a problem with the last element duplicated that's not removed but I solved doing the cycle 2 times.

Comment: you can edit answer and submit for other members ; tanx alot

Answer (score 2):

If you can, you should use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), or any other set class. It is much more efficient for this kind of operation. The main default of the HashSet is that the ordering of the element is not guaranteed to remain the same as your original list (wich may or may not be a problem, depending on your specifications).

Otherwise, if you need to keep the ordering, but only need the duplicates removed when you enumerate through your values, you can use the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method from linq. Just be careful and don't run this query and copy the result everytime you modify your arraylist as it risks impacting your performances.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        foreach (string item in originalArray){
            //set a key in the hashtable for our arraylist value - leaving the hashtable value empty
            ht[item] = null;
        }

    //now grab the keys from that hashtable into another arraylist
    ArrayList distincArray = new ArrayList(ht.Keys);
```

Comment: Before the above code add the  line: Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

Answer (score -1):

If you must use ArrayList, use the **Sort** method.
Here's a good link @ [Sort Method of ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx).
After the list is sorted, then use an algorithm to iterate/compare all your elements and remove the duplicates.

Have fun,

Tommy Kwee

Comment: i am not wanted sorting but want remove duplicate.

Comment: @Mitesh, After the list is sorted, you can remove duplicates by iterating all the elements.

Comment: The Distinct method  removes the duplicates by itself. If you're to use a linq method, use the right one.

Comment: @Falanwe, Isn't the Distinct method only available for string arrays. Is it also available in ArrayList?

Comment: it's a linq method: it's available on every type that implements IEnumerable<T>.