# Removing Duplicates "ABD" "BAD" "DAB" from a list of permutations

Tags: c#

I have a rather large list of strings that contains duplicates in the sense that if I only care if A,B,C are in a result, but not what order they are in.  I looked for many other duplication removal solutions, but they typically only work for exact values(which I understand since these elements aren't exact dups, but more spurious or superfluous results.)  I already have the list and didn't create it, so changing the selection is not an option.

Comment: Are the results variable length?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Offtop: so frank and self-critic user name

Comment: @DanilAsotsky, the OP is looking for removing duplicate permutations, not duplicate values.

Comment: they are the same length, but I would also like to know how to do variable length if anyone knows how to accomplish that.

Comment: @nicholas +1, but you *could* use `HashSet` if you sorted the string in the Hash function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply sort the elements within each item first.

```
listOfStrings.Select(s => new string(s.OrderBy(c => c))).Distinct().ToList();
```

You see what I mean - sort the chars.  I'll check the syntax of this momentarily..

Comment: ah, beat me to it. see what i was getting at with the same-length question?

Comment: @nicholas yeah, me too. You gave me the idea!!