# remove duplicate words from string in C#

Tags: c#

here is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sentence = string.Empty;
            sentence = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] sent = sentence.Split(' ');
            //to be sorted alphabetically
            var x =
                from k in sent
                orderby k
                select k;

            foreach (string s in x)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(s.ToLower());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

is there any method to find and remove duplicate words or I should make my own method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Distinct:

```
foreach (string s in x.Distinct())
{
        Console.WriteLine(s.ToLower());
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use Linq's [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) extension method:

```
var sent = sentence.Split(' ').Distinct();
```

You can also use this to ignore the case of strings when comparing them—e.g. `"WORD"` and `"word"` would be considered duplicates:

```
var sent = sentence.Split(' ').Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use System.Linq [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx):

```
foreach (string s in x.Distinct())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do everything you're asking:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sentence = string.Empty;
        sentence = Console.ReadLine();

        var sent = sentence
            .Split(' ')
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x);

        foreach (string s in sent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.ToLower());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simple Remove Duplicate words form string by using for loop.
try this it's working fine.

```
string SetenceString = "red white black white green yellow red red black white";
        string[] data = SetenceString.Split(' ');
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            string temp = " ";
            if (i == 0)
            {
                temp = data[i].ToString();
                sb = sb.Append(temp + " ");

            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < data.Length; j++)
                {
                    string temp2 = data[j].ToString();
                    string strnew = sb.ToString();
                    string[] Kdata = strnew.Split(' ');
                    bool isnoduplicate = false;
                    for (int k = 0; k < Kdata.Length; k++)
                    {
                        string temp3 = Kdata[k].ToString();

                      if (temp3 != "")
                        {
                            if (temp2 == temp3)
                            {
                                isnoduplicate = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isnoduplicate = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (isnoduplicate)
                    {
                        sb = sb.Append(temp2 + " ");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
        Console.ReadKey();
```