# Replace multiple character by single character in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to replace my string by single charter if any string is continuously coming.

Say for example, I have string format like this.

```
 string str="eeexampple"
```

I need to replace all the repeated charters by single character. So my expected output will be something like this.

```
  "example"
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove duplicate words from string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368834/remove-duplicate-words-from-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't know why these many down votes. @fubo has given me the exact solution what I expected.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV - result is `exampl` instead of `example`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a simple method, probably there is a more elegant way in linq to solve this problem

```
public static string RemoveDuplicates(string input)
{
    string sResult = string.Empty;
    char cTemp = '\0';
    foreach (char cItem in input)
    {
        if (cItem != cTemp)
        {
            sResult += cItem;
        }
        cTemp = cItem;
    }
    return sResult;
}
```

usage:

```
string str = "eeexampple";
string output = RemoveDuplicates(str);
```

Comment: I like this solution. Simple.

Comment: Thanks.. Its working fine..! I expected this answer only.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex! -- Use the much more succinct ```Regex``` method below!

Answer (score 5):

here is a approach with RegEx:

```
string str = "eeexampple";
string output = Regex.Replace(str, "(.)\\1+","$1");
```

Comment: Beware! This _'solution'_ will eliminate _ALL_ instances of two duplicate characters that it finds! This includes, for example, turning words like 'boot' into 'bot' and 'happy' into 'hapy' etc. A better regex would be: ```Regex.Replace( str, @"(.)\1{2,}", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );```  Which removes triplets and more, but ignores double-characters. Use the ```RegexOptions.IgnoreCase``` option to also correct instances where the extra characters include mixed case, like turning ```"aaaAaAAaaaaA"``` into just ```a```.