# How to remove duplicate tests with duplicate outcomes using C#?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, distinct, trx

So I have a big list with tests that possibly are run maximum 3 times, and possibly have the same message 2 times, and the third time it could have a distinct message than the previous two runs. I am trying to implement a code that will show only unique tests, with unique outcomes.
To have a better view, this would be a use case:

`testname="TestABC"    errormessage="ErrXYZ"`
`testname="Test3454"   errormessage="Err123"`
`testname="TestABC"    errormessage="Err123"`
`testname="TestABC"    errormessage="ErrXYZ"`
`testname="Test3454"   errormessage="ErrYTR"`
`testname="Test3454"   errormessage="ErrABC"`

As you can see, "TestABC" appears 2 times with the same error, and one time with a different error. I would like to see the following output after the filtering:

`testname="TestABC"    errormessage="ErrXYZ"`
`testname="Test3454"   errormessage="Err123"`
`testname="TestABC"    errormessage="Err123"`
`testname="Test3454"   errormessage="ErrYTR"`
`testname="Test3454"   errormessage="ErrABC"`

I am quite new to C#, and would appreciate any help or guidance.
Thanks!

Comment: You have a `List<TestClass>`, don't you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to implement `IEqualityComparer` interface  and use `Distinct` method

```
class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Test>
{
    public bool Equals(Test x, Test y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.testname, y.testname) && string.Equals(x.errormessage, y.errormessage);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Test obj)
    {
        string name = string.Format ("{0}{1}", obj.testname, obj.errormessage);
        int hash = 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + name[i];
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

And if you use `List` use `Distinct` method

```
testList.Distinct(new Comparer())
```

But I suggest to use [Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) with the `IEqualityComparer`.