# Remove duplicate lists inside a list of lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq

How do I remove duplicate inner lists from main list?

```
var list1 = new List<object>() { 1,2,3 };
var list2 = new List<object>() { 4,5,6 };
var list3 = new List<object>() { 1,2,3 };

List<List<object>> mainList = new List<List<object>>() {list1, list2, list3};
```

I want to remove the `list3` from the `mainList` so that no duplicates in the `mainList`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Just remove the list from the list of lists `mainList.Remove(list3)`

Comment: Do you want to remove a specific list, or remove all the duplicates?

Comment: @chayim-friedman I want to remove all the duplicates

Comment: @Rango It must be list of objects.

Comment: Would `{3,2,1}` be considered a duplicate? (Same values different order)

Comment: @Magnus Yes, {3,2,1} considered as duplicate

Comment: @nff I've update my answer so that `{3, 2, 1}` would also be considered as duplicate. please use the updated code. previous code was wrong (according to your needs).

Comment: what about `{3, 3, 2, 1, 1}`? is that duplicate of `{1, 2, 3}` as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** as mentioned in comments, order of items does not matter so `{3,2,1}` and `{1,2,3}` are considered duplicate.

---

There are a few concerns about your question. your inner list contains objects. if that means object can be anything and not just an `int` then you should make sure those objects override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` as well (or implement `IEquatable<TSelf>` where `TSelf` is the implementing type).

If your inner list just contains primitive types or common readonly structs such as DateTime or TimeSpan then you shouldn't worry.

You can use Distinct and EqualityComparer interface

```
var list1 = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<object>() { 4, 5, 6 };
var list3 = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3 };

List<List<object>> mainList = new List<List<object>>() { list1, list2, list3 };

mainList = mainList.Distinct(ListEqualityComparer<object>.Default).ToList();
```

Equality comparer implementation.

```
public class ListEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<T> _itemEqualityComparer;

    public ListEqualityComparer() : this(null) { }

    public ListEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> itemEqualityComparer)
    {
        _itemEqualityComparer = itemEqualityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public static readonly ListEqualityComparer<T> Default = new ListEqualityComparer<T>();

    public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        return x.Count == y.Count && !x.Except(y, _itemEqualityComparer).Any();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> list)
    {
        int hash = 17;
        foreach (var itemHash in list.Select(x => _itemEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(x))
                                     .OrderBy(h => h))
        {
            hash += 31 * itemHash;
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

If your objects does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you can make another equality comparer for your items as well and pass it to this equality comparer.

```
mainList = mainList.Distinct(new ListEqualityComparer<object>(myItemEqualityComparer)).ToList();
```

where `myItemEqualityComparer` is for comparing your `object`s

Comment: `mainList = mainList.Distinct(new ListEqualityComparer<object>()).ToList();` ?

Comment: @woldemar no need of `ToList()` in this case

Comment: Apparently should the order not matter (see comment on the question). `{3,2,1}` is a duplicate.

Comment: @Magnus I've addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try following linq uery

```
var list1 = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<object>() { 4, 5, 6 };
var list3 = new List<object>() { 3, 1, 2 };

List<List<object>> mainList = new List<List<object>>() { list1, list2, list3 };

var distinctlist = mainList.Select(o => 
    { 
        var t = o.OrderBy(x=>x).Select(i => i.ToString()); 
        return new { Key= string.Join("", t),List=o }; 
    })
    .GroupBy(o => o.Key)
    .Select(o => o.FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(o => o.List);
```