# How can ı remove from duplicated items in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates, unique

I have a list in the below it has **18 value**.I have another *list(include **unique 6 value**)* created by random numbers(1,18), and they are unique.
When i do these for example `elidenkiKartlar` list shows me 6 unique values, but i have 2 list more in other lists, I have same values for example in `elindekiKartlar=K1,K3,S4,RD-1,S2,M4` in another list `K1,K4,RD-2,S4,K3`, i have same values `(K1,K3)` e.g.
How can i remove them ? How can I share this big list to 3 equal(6,6,6) part ?
Thanks for your advise from now..

```
  public List<string> kartlar = new List<string>
    {
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "S4",
        "S5",
        "M1",
        "M2",
        "M3",
        "M4",
        "M5",
        "K1",
        "K2",
        "K3",
        "K4",
        "K5",
        "RD-1",
        "RD-2",
        "RD-3",
    };

      //Creating uniqe random list

            int [] sayilar=new int[6];

            for (int i = 0; i < sayilar.Length; i++)
            {
                essiz:
                sayilar[i] = random.Next(0, 18);
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (sayilar[i]==sayilar[j])
                    {
                        goto essiz;
                    }

                }
            }


  //Adding string items by randomList index 

            foreach (var sayi in sayilar)
        {
            elindekiKartlar.Add(kartlar[sayi]);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Distinct Method`

```
var uniqueValues = kartlar.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: kartlar ıs a unıqe lıst dıstınct doesnt work.My sımple questıon ıs how can ı share my lıst to 3 uniqe part?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
elindekiKartlar.Distinct();
```