# My algorithm for removing a duplicate from a list is not removing all duplicates

Tags: c#

The code only removes duplicates apart from the last 2 of any number

```
for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.Count; i = i + 1)
{
   for (int j = i + 1; j < primeNumbers.Count; j = j + 1)
   {
      if (primeNumbers[i] == primeNumbers[j])
      {
          primeNumbers.RemoveAt(j); 
         

      }
   }
}

for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(primeNumbers[i]);
```

Comment: visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Comment: yeah I have checked those, thanks guys. :)

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question after it's been answered, as my now accepted answer doesn't bear any resemblance to the original question you asked.  You should have asked a new question

Comment: Yup, I've reverted it back  to its original - sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner for loop will skip the next entry after the remove.  After the remove, decrement j so that it will recheck the current entry on the next loop.

So add `j--;`

Comment: ah yes that worked a treat thank you, you got any ideas how I could improve the time complexity right now?

Answer (score 3):

To improve time complexity, use a Set. A Set cannot have duplicates. Just iterate once through your list, and add each value to the set.

Complexity will be linear O(n).

Comment: I'm sorry my question is too remove from an existing list of numbers, not too add and not include. My solution right now isn't quite working

Comment: I know. But it's more effecient to create a Set and to remove duplicates this way, and then to copy the set to a list.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple and elegant:

```
const noDupes = primeNumbers.filter((item, ind, arr) => ind === arr.indexOf(item));
```

HTH

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code you posted isn't C#

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code to improve:

If your primeNumbers is an Array[]:

```
primeNumbers = primeNumbers.Distinct().ToArray();
```

If your primeNumbers is an List<>:

```
primeNumbers = primeNumbers.Distinct().ToList();
```

If your primeNumbers is an HashSet<>:

```
primeNumbers = primeNumbers.Distinct().ToHashSet();
```

**EXTRA**
When filling up your list of primenumbers, use HashSet

```
HashSet primeNumbers = new();
primeNumbers.Add(number);
```

It will automatically remove the duplicates.

This collection is introduced in . NET 3.5.

Comment: yea im using a list :), so how would i implement this hashset?

Comment: If you use a list already, simply call yourlist.Distinct();

In case you want HashSet, replace your List with HashSet (declaration or primenumbers)
Adding the numbers t a list and HashSet is the same, with the . Add method