# ASP.NET Claims identity remove duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims

I was wondering if there is a method in order to remove duplicate from claims

this is my extract code:

```
 var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);



foreach (Delegation d in delegations)


{

List<string> delegateRoles = await (from r in _dbContext.Roles 
                             where (del.DelegatedId == user.UserId)
                             select r.RoleName).Distinct().ToListAsync();

foreach (string role in delegateRoles)
{
   if (DelegatorUserRoles.Contains(role))
   {
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("DelegatedRole", role));
                         
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that I can have multiple delegations with the same roles, so I want to delete duplicates

Comment: Just filter list with distinct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @rajatJha how to select distinct in identity variable? it has array of objcets identity -> Claims -> list of claims

Comment: just first store it in the string list then distinct

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but to someone who stumbles upon this question at some point (like I did).

Specific method for removing duplicates which are already added? No, it does not exist. Can you do it yourself? Absolutely.

What I did:

```
public sealed class UserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User, Role>
{
    // ...

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(User user)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        if (identity.Claims is not IList<Claim> claimList)
        {
            claimList = identity.Claims.ToList();
        }

        // Remove duplicate capabilities
        var duplicateCapabilityClaims = claimList
            .Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Capabilities)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(x => x.SkipLast(1));
        foreach (var claim in duplicateCapabilityClaims)
        {
            identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
        }

        return identity;
    }
}
```

This one is for claims generated by ASP.NET Core Identity which just dumps whatever the roles have in their claims, possibly duplicating the same capabilities twice or more. I have no control in what actually gets put into the claims inside base `GenerateClaimsAsync` call.

On the other hand, it looks like in your code sample you could just use a `HashSet<string>` to keep track of actually distinct roles, similar to this:

```
List<string> delegateRoles = await (from r in _dbContext.Roles 
                             where (del.DelegatedId == user.UserId)
                             select r.RoleName).Distinct().ToListAsync();
HashSet<string> uniqueDelegateRoles = delegateRoles.ToHashSet();

foreach (string role in uniqueDelegateRoles)
{
    if (DelegatorUserRoles.Contains(role)) // Not sure what this is as the snippet is incomplete, but keeping it
    {
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("DelegatedRole", role));
    }
}
```

Then you should no longer have any duplicates for this specific claim type.

Your question asks whether it's possible to remove the duplicates (it is; not straight out of the box), but in your case it's probably a better idea to not even add the duplicate claims in the first place (so, the second example).